# Bug that disappears when attempting to study it

Tags: c++, debugging

This is the most weird thing that has ever happened to me when programming in C++.

This is my main file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "lib/utils.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    cout << bin2dec(101000010);
    return 0;
}
```

and this is lib/utils.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "utils.h"

int bin2dec(int bin) {
    // 101000010
    int dec;
    //std::cout << "";  // If you uncomment this, it works.
    for (int i = 1; bin > 0; i *= 2, bin /= 10) {
        if (bin % 2 == 1) {
            dec += i;
        }
    }
    return dec;
}
```

The program compiles with no warnings, and when run, it outputs `450`. 450 is not 101000010 in decimal, 322 is. The first weird thing is that the difference between 482 and 322 is exactly 128. This happens with any binary number you try to convert. But what's REALLY weird, is that when I tried to output the value of `bin` and `dec` inside the `for` in an attempt to debug the function, it suddenly started working correctly.

Basically, for some reason, if you `std::cout` something before the function returns, it works. If you don't, it adds 128 to the result.

I'm using g++ 4.6.0, and compiling like this:

```
g++ -c   -D NDEBUG -O2     -o 10.o 10.cpp
g++ -c   -D NDEBUG -O2     -o lib/utils.o lib/utils.cpp
g++  -o 10   -Wl,-S  10.o lib/utils.o lib/menu.o
```

Comment: This is extremely common - welcome to the world of undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Doug Perhaps you can explain to me what the question is?

Comment: At a minimum, you should be explicitly initializing dec.

Comment: Could this be a manifestation of the uncertainty principle?

Comment: +1 for a well asked question and reminding me how weird things can get when you don't initialize variables.

Comment: @Benjamin: hence the term "Heisenbug". Moves whenever you look at it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You're not initializing dec.

```
int dec = 0;
```

Comment: @Gerado you shouldn't :P The odder the mistake, the more "stupid" of a mistake you made :P we've all been there, and we're all go there again

Answer (score 16):

The small bug is that you are not initializing the `dec` variable.

The bigger bug is that you are not used to add `-Wall` and `-O2` when compiling (something that will cause a lot of pain as the programs you write will become more complex).

`-Wall` enables all warnings and `-O2` requires optimization (optimization includes code path analysis that will raise warnings about uninitialized variables).

Comment: Beat me to it. Always use -Wall. Sometimes -Wall isn't enough. Compiling with -Wall and optimization will find things like uninitialized variables.

Comment: @David Hammen: True... requesting optimization is important to see more warnings. Edited my reply.

Comment: Wall *does not* enable all warnings. There are quite a few warnings that -Wall does not catch. I use -Wall -Wold-style-cast -Woverloaded-virtual -Wshadow. I would add -Weffc++ to the mix were it not for the fact that doing so generates a lot of noise from GNU's implementation of the standard library.

Comment: Optimization request to get more warning is only true of g++, clang warns about uninitialized variables even at `-O0`...

Answer (score 3):

```
int dec;
```

Creates `dec` but never gives it an initial value (like 0). You then add values to it, and end up with a random result.

Answer (score 3):

You need to initialize `dec` to zero in your function:

```
int dec = 0;
```

By not initializing it, it starts at whatever random crud is in memory at the variable's location.  And the call to `cout <<` can affect what crud is in that area, hence the changes.  By the way, when I tried your code, I wasn't getting `450`.  I was getting `134514688` which gives an example of this.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simply, your problem screams stack or heap smashing to me- probably stack, since all the operations of the function are on the stack. You don't get to this kind of problem without invoking some nasty undefined behaviour elsewhere in the program.

Edit: Oh yeah- you could start by initializing `dec`, just for example.